# Correct way to parse JSON values vie cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, json, parsing, cpprest-sdk

Trying to figure out a general to-go way for JSON value parsing.

- No error checking:

  ```
  myField = jsonValue["myField"].as_string();`
  ```
- With error checking:

  ```
  if (jsonValue.is_null())
      return false;

  if (!jsonValue.is_object())
      return false;

  for (auto it = jsonValue.as_object().cbegin(); it != jsonValue.as_object().cend(); ++it)
  {
      const std::string& str = it->first;
      const json::value& v = it->second;

      if (str == "myField")
      {
          if (v.is_string())
          {
              myField = v.as_string();
              continue;
          }
          else
          {
              return false;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

The difference in amount of code is noticeable. Should I bother with error checking or the first approach would be enough?

Comment: Maybe validate your json with a json-schema before processing it ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Working with JSON for the first time. Quick search just points me to several online validators.

Comment: json schema is a way to describe expected json: (should have field "myField" of type string, ...). So you can handle error from schema first. If no errors from schema, you can avoid some error checking.

Answer (score 0):

This question would probably be best suited at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but if you have a requirement to handle errors gracefully, you should prefer code that has robust error handling.